# MASM: Access Violation Writing Location

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

using MASM 8086 
program determines the largest value in the given arrays
Unhandled exception gets thrown when esi is increased. This does not appear to happen when largestVal is defined as a DWORD. However, this prevents .IF largestVal < ebx from working.

```
Include Irvine32.inc

FindLargest PROTO, pArr: PTR DWORD, Count: DWORD

.data

str1 BYTE "arr1: ", 0
str2 BYTE "arr2: ", 0
str3 BYTE "arr3: ", 0

arr1 SDWORD +1122h, +2233h, -3344h
arr2 SDWORD +2233h, +3344h, +4455h, +6677h

.code

main PROC
call Clrscr

INVOKE FindLargest, ADDR arr1, LENGTHOF arr1
mov edx, OFFSET str1
call WriteString    
call WriteInt       


INVOKE FindLargest, ADDR arr2, LENGTHOF arr2
mov edx, OFFSET str2
call WriteString
call WriteInt

exit
main ENDP

FindLargest PROC USES ebx ecx esi, pArr: PTR DWORD, Count: DWORD
LOCAL largestVal: SDWORD

mov esi, pArr       
mov ecx, Count
mov largestVal, -2147483648

L1:

mov ebx, [esi]

.IF largestVal < ebx

mov largestVal, ebx

.ENDIF

add esi, 4                 ; Where exception gets thrown                
loop L1

mov eax, largestVal         
ret
FindLargest ENDP
END main
```

Comment: No problem here, but look at `INVOKE FindLargest, ADDR arr3, LENGTHOF arr2`. You're scanning `arr3` with the length of `arr2`.

Comment: fixed, but I am still getting errors during runtime. Exception thrown at 0x004036B2 in maxLength.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00401055.

Comment: I can't reproduce the exception here. Everything works fine. Sorry.

Comment: I changed the last element in arr1 to -3344h. On your end, does this produce the result 8755 and 26231 on console?

Comment: Yes. And I played a lot more with the arrays and the declarations (values, sizes, types). I built the program with "Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 10.00.40219.01" and called it under WinXP (32-bit) and Win7 (64 bit). There must be anything wrong with your environment. Is there some strange security software working in the background?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 with Windows 10 (64-bit). I am able to compile other .asm files with this setup so I'm not sure why this doesn't work. I will try installing Microsoft Macro Assembler later and see it that works.

Comment: Okay I've got the exception. It's a "feature" of VS2015. The program assembles, links and works in VS2013. I'm looking for a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a feature of VS2015. The code works fine with VS2013

Visual Studio 2015 stumbles over this line:

```
.IF largestVal < ebx
```

and produces total crap, amongst others the address `ebp-7D` for `largestVal` that is beyound the stack frame. Correct is `ebp-4`.

I've figured out two workarounds.

1) Decouple `largestVal` from the `.IF` directive:

```
...
mov eax, largestVal
.IF eax < ebx
mov largestVal, ebx
.ENDIF
...
```

2) Don't use the MASM preprocessor, use pure assembly instructions instead:

```
...
cmp largestVal, ebx
jge @F                  ; Jump forward to the next @@
mov largestVal, ebx
@@:
...
```